# alert in background ( ios 7 )

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to create alert in background like the alert of the clock app. 
i tried to use UILocalNotification but the alertAction doesn't appear in the background 
this show me only the notification on top.

pic for example:

[image]

Comment: In your settings app under Notification Center ... let your app **Alert Style** to be **Alerts**

Comment: Alert type is depends on your alert style is selected of your app notification center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't control the way the notifications appear in iOS 5 and up, simply because the user has a choice of the settings of the notifications:
[image]

Comment: so i cant make a custom alert ?

Comment: @user2915374 the answer is - no, you can't

Comment: and one more thing , you can cancel the return to app after clicked on the action button ?

Comment: @user2915374 as far as I know only when the user pressed "cancel"

Comment: and i can rename the cancel button ?

Comment: @user2915374 you have no direct control over the pop-up as far as I can remember, it's not like creating a `UIAlertView`